# Response.Redirect not working from a C# file

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I have a web page , `Response.aspx`, the code behind file for this is `Response.aspx.cs` . This file contains the code to parse the url parameters and save them to the database, and this file is called as a callback url from another web application as

```
wwww.myswbsite.com/response.aspx?id1=1
```

where in the `response.aspx.cs` file, the value of `id` is read and written to the database in the `Page_Load` function.

Now, once the data is written to the database, I want the web page to redirect from whatever is the current one to a new one such as "Learn.aspx". In the page load function , I have added the code , `Response.Redirect("Learn.aspx")` , but this does not seem to redirect anywhere. In fact , if I instead type the command `www.mywebsite.com/response.aspx` in the browser , then it redirects to the new Learn.aspx page , but when the url is being called as a callback, the Response.Redirect function does not seem to be working but the code is coming into the page load function as the values are being written into the database.

Any help to solve this is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Please post your Response.aspx.cs source

Comment: Please elaborate how you're making "callback" to the Response.aspx. I have a feeling you're doing redirect in a wrong place and should do it in the caller instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying you want to redirect the 3rd party web application (which calls your page) - you can't.

Return a response which indicates to the 3rd party application that they should perform a redirect.

For example, you could return a json response like this:

```
{
    "redirect": true,
    "redirectUrl": "http://mysite.com/learn.aspx"
}
```

And then in the 3rd party application, something like this:

```
// code to call your application here

if (jsonResponse.redirect == true)
{
    Response.Redirect(jsonResponse.redirectUrl);
}
```

Comment: Sean appreciate your quick response. Actually, a third party application is simply calling a web page on my site...the purpose of calling that url is simply to pass certain paramaters in the url. Once I am in the page_load function of my web page's code behind file and am able to run my c# statements, for example to part the url, then why cannot I also execute the command to redirect the web site, after all the asp.net application is running on my server . Sounds strange to me...

Comment: @kabir when you say calling, do you mean making a web request to your site or redirecting to your site?

Comment: making a web request to our site

Comment: yeah you won't be able to redirect them automatically because the scope of control isn't in your web application. your web application runs your page when it's requested, inserts your records into your DB, and spits out a response, which is then sent back to the 3rd party app. it's up to them how they deal with the response, which is why in my answer i mentioned you should send them back a response asking them to redirect.

Comment: it's also worth pointing out that a Response.Redirect just issues 302 redirect, which the browser has to handle. in a web request, there's not really a "browser" in a traditional sense, hence nothing to handle the redirect.

Comment: Would a Server.Transfer command be able to achieve the redirect that I am trying to get m  in this case ?

Comment: no - see my answer. you have to send a response back to the 3rd party app and let the 3rd party app redirect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39784/discussion-between-kabir-and-seanxe)